# Remove Register top.link

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, toplinks

I know how to do this in a general sense, except for whatever reason, I can't get it to work properly on a second website. My second website is merely a subdomain of my main, so https://second.mywebsite.com. I'm using a different layout/theme for when I need to make custom changes to just the second site, so I've switched the `layout` and `template` package to `second` under **Config > General > Design**

I have attempted to remove the original Register link through `customer.xml`, in order to add a new one that points to my main site's registration page.

What I have:

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl" translate="label title" module="customer">
    <label>Register</label>
    <url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/>
    <title>Register</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>99</position>
</action>
```

Now, this works on every single page for my second website, **except** for the homepage.  I cannot figure out why only the homepage is forcing the original Register link to show up.

Answer (score 0):

After more searching, and then a little more, I checked the CMS page for the homepage of the second site.

**CMS > Pages**

Turns out that in **Design > Custom Design**, the `Custom Theme` was set to the custom theme of the main site and not the directory for the second site's changes.  So, just the homepage was reading the main site's theme directory and ignoring any changes made in the second site's theme directory. So simply changing that fixed the entire issue....